# How to redirect after self post form with filter attributes?

Tags: php

I'm wondering how to redirect to my same URL "X" after submitting my form with

`X?name=$name&y=$y&z=$z`

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<div>
    <label for="searchterm">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="searchterm">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="submit"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Basically you don't. You do all your form processing *before* any HTML display, and then send the updated HTML form. Also, you can put nothing (or "?") in the `action` to ensure the form will go to the same script that generated it.

Comment: The question is open to quite some different interpretations, but how I read is that he wants to submit to URL X, and then after the post data is processed there he wants to redirect with a GET to the same URL X. That's just a regular 303 See Other redirect by the book to prevent repeatable requests and makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you are looking for an `GET` request.

In this case, just delete your method from the form, as `GET` is default for html forms:

```
<form id="myform" name="myform" <!-- >> HERE: method="post" << --> action="">
<div>
    <label for="searchterm">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="searchterm">
</div>
<div>
    <label for="submit"></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Filter">
</div>
</form>
```

Then you will see that your url has the ending you described.

You can fetch the data via

```
$_GET['searchterm'];
```

and

```
$_GET['submit'];
```

in your file thereafter.

You could check for $_GET at the beginning of your file by

```
if (isset($_GET['submit'])) {
// do something awesome 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I got everything in my URL now to get and display from my DB from.

Comment: You are welcome! Please make sure to protect you DB queries. It's not safe to query your database with unfiltered userinput. You can read more about this [here](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: No worries. Got all that covered in class. Was just trying to figure out this home page where you search and display on the same page with mass filtering.

Answer (score 0):

```
header('HTTP/1.1 303 See other');
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
die;
```